# Need to transfer ~3TB of data to a remote server

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy large file from one Linux server to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/53531/copy-large-file-from-one-linux-server-to-another)

I need to transfer about ~3tb of data to another server. I am currently using rsync -z but it is going at 250kb/s so it will take forever. How can I speed it up?

Comment: Buy a bigger pipe or sneaker net.

Comment: I am assuiming you have already compressed the data.

Comment: I haven't compressed the data yet but wouldn't that take forever?

Comment: Would transferring 3tb at 250kb not also take forever? there is no magic solution.

Comment: What kind of link are you transferring over (on both ends)? I agree, [sneaker net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet#Non-fiction) is probably the best option.

Comment: I have 1gbps on both

Comment: Can you tell us more about the hardware, what is the load in both sides?

Comment: Using http://monalisa.cern.ch/FDT/ I am now transferring at 300mb/s

Answer (score 9):

Mail a hard drive to the server and have a technician plug it in.

Comment: I agree. This is probably the fastest, most cost effective way of getting it done.

Comment: Yep, this is were the old pigeon beats the inter-tubes. It'll have to be a big heavy-duty pigeon, but still :-) This is also a good opportunity to keep an archive/backup on a bunch of hard disks, kept in a vault.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers where you have much larger packet sizes.  Oh, and UDP.

Comment: +1 "Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway." -Andrew Tanenbaum

Answer (score -1):

You can try to split data into let's say 3000 pieces using `split` command and transfer it using netcat (`nc` or `netcat` command) over UDP. It's usually faster than TCP. Then you can `rsync` them to make sure it all gets transferred correctly.

Comment: Academic answer - correct but totally useless. It wont magially make thigns 100 times faster and that is what is needed here. A mere 25% faster upload wont solve the problem.